# Convert tuples to list of dictionary

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble converting two tuples into a list of dictionaries. Here is the structure:

```
train_detail = (Counter({2: 50, 0: 62, 1: 38}),
 {2: 0.3333333333333333, 0: 0.41333333333333333, 1: 0.25333333333333335})

test_detail = (Counter({2: 6, 0: 49, 1: 4}),
 {2: 0.1016949152542373, 0: 0.8305084745762712, 1: 0.06779661016949153})
```

Now i want to turn these two into a structure like the following:

```
 [
        {
            "label": "0",
            "trainPercent": 0.41333333333333333,
            "trainNumber": 62,
            "testPercent": 0.8305084745762712,
            "testNumber": 49,
        },
        {
            "label": "1",
            "trainPercent": 0.25333333333333335,
            "trainNumber": 38,
            "testPercent": 0.06779661016949153,
            "testNumber": 4,
        },
        {
            "label": "2",
            "trainPercent": 0.3333333333333333,
            "trainNumber": 50,
            "testPercent": 0.1016949152542373,
            "testNumber": 6,
        },      
    ]
```

What's an effective way of doing that with minimum looping? Thank you. Note **Counter** is a subclass of dict so inherited every methods of a regular dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pprint import pprint
from collections import Counter


train_detail = (Counter({2: 50, 0: 62, 1: 38}),
 {2: 0.3333333333333333, 0: 0.41333333333333333, 1: 0.25333333333333335})

test_detail = (Counter({2: 6, 0: 49, 1: 4}),
 {2: 0.1016949152542373, 0: 0.8305084745762712, 1: 0.06779661016949153})

out = []
for t in train_detail[0]:
    out.append({
        'label': str(t),
        'trainNumber': train_detail[0][t],
        'trainPercent': train_detail[1][t],
        'testPercent': test_detail[1][t],
        'testNumber': test_detail[0][t]
    })

# pretty print to screen:
pprint(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'label': '2',
  'testNumber': 6,
  'testPercent': 0.1016949152542373,
  'trainNumber': 50,
  'trainPercent': 0.3333333333333333},
 {'label': '0',
  'testNumber': 49,
  'testPercent': 0.8305084745762712,
  'trainNumber': 62,
  'trainPercent': 0.41333333333333333},
 {'label': '1',
  'testNumber': 4,
  'testPercent': 0.06779661016949153,
  'trainNumber': 38,
  'trainPercent': 0.25333333333333335}]
```

Comment: A list comprehension also does the trick and might be more readable. If the result needs to be sorted, you may want to sort the keys before iterating or add `sorted(res, key=lambda x: int(x["label"]))`

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda function.lambda is used to unpack tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Andrej Kesely and @Björn Marschollek

To combine their answers:

```
labels_detail_list = [{'label': str(i), 
                       'trainNumber': train_detail[0][i], 
                       'trainPercent': train_detail[1][i],
                       'testNumber': test_detail[0][i],
                       'testPercent': test_detail[1][i]
                      } for i in train_detail[0]]

sorted(labels_detail_list, key=lambda x: int(x['label']))
```

should be more concise version.